# understanding any network [i.e. infiniband] maximum file transfer speed

Tags: networking, file-copy

[Mellanox] infiniband HDR I have to work with is stated to be 100 gbps.

In doing a single file copy of `my30gb.tar` with `rsync --progress` I observed a max of 480 MB/sec and an average of ~460 MB/sec on subsequent copies, assuming after the first the `my30gb.tar` was cached in ram so I was not being limited by read speed from the installed SAS SSD.  And that the write to the destination of the 30gb tar file would be going into RAM initially.  The source and destination server both have 700GB RAM.

Over copper 1gbps using samba doing the same kind of copy from win10 to/from my server I always get a solid 112 MB/sec.  So that is my reference point.  For example:

[image]

If my infiniband HDR is 100x, why doesn't my `rsync --progress` show close to 100x speed improvement?  I only see ~450 MB/sec  of hoping to have observed 112,000 MB/sec.  450 / 112,000 is less than 1% improvement?  Confused.

*I realize the advertised infiniband network speed is in bits per second, but I am looking for something I can relate to which is expected file transfer speed in bytes per second and time it'll take for large files to transfer*

Between my 2 linux servers on infiniband HDR, having no other overhead or traffic, the NFS connection was v4.1 and protocol TCP.  I got protocol RDMA working and still observed the same transfer values using that one 30gb tar file.

Is there network tuning or nfs tuning that can/should be done?  **What maximum file transfer speed should I expect to achieve over infiniband HDR if everything is done properly?**  Looking to understand the limiting factors as it pertains to file copy speed over NFS over some network, whether it is 1gbps copper, or 100gbps infiniband, or whatever.  If anyone has insight using previous generation of infiniband... FDR, EDR, QDR and whatever they were that were faster than 1 gbps copper, I'd love an information you could provide.

The mount NFS mount arguments are the default and show up as

```
(rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1,_netdev)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get sustained, near link speed, read/write performance with NVMEoF, given careful configuration. Careful configuration includes things like: Do you have enough PCIe bandwidth to handle your NIC? A PCIe Gen 3 by 16 lanes slot is only fast enough for one 100 Gbit Infiniband link. Then you have to make sure you have enough PCIe bandwidth, enough PCIe lanes, to get your data to NVME array and if you are using 4 lane NVME devices, that you distribute your devices across the lanes available in the computer. You want to make sure your NIC and NVME array are on the same PCIe host in the computer. You need to think about what other things are using that PCIe bandwidth.

With Infiniband and other high speed networking, it becomes important to keep the kernel, the CPU, interrupts, etc. out of the data transfers. They are often the limiting factors. One of the worst is the CPU having to touch the buffers.

One key advantage to Infiniband is the ability to do Remote Direct Memory Access, RDMA, without any CPU intervention. You are moving data from memory through the Network Interface Card, NIC, to the remote computers NIC and then DMA'd directly into memory.

First make sure Infiniband, the NIC, and the NVidia (Mellanox) OFED are configured correctly and are doing the advertised 100 gbps. You can do this with the NVidia supplied "perftest".

The Infiniband Send Bandwidth, ib_send_bw, test is a place to start.

On one Infiniband connected computer run just "ib_send_bw". On the other run "ib_send_bw XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP address of the Infiband adapter of the first computer.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/fi/linux-on-systems?topic=linuxonibm/performance/howtos/verifyrdma.htm

You can also use iperf3 or netcat (nc) to get an estimate. For example this question and answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/7976/how-do-you-test-the-network-speed-between-two-boxes

rsync, by default wants to do delta/diff comparisons, which involves the CPU reading buffers. Compression or using rsync with ssh will kill your performance since, again, the CPU will need to read and manipulate all the data. There are advantages to use something already capable of transferring data without CPU involvement, such as NVME over Fabric (NVMEoF), iSCSI, and others.